Does registering as a voter in Washington State, USA make it more likely to be selected for jury duties?
Does registering as a voter in Washington State, USA make you more likely to be selected for jury duties? I see that jury duties are mentioned in the online voter registration form, which makes me wonder about the impact of registering to vote on jury duties.

"...make it more likely to be selected for jury duties?" Make it more likely, than what? Registering as a voter in say Oregon, Massachusetts, Texas, etc?  Or do you mean, if you don't register to vote in WA, are you less likely than a registered voter to be called up to Jury Duty?

@BruceWayne than not registering

@FranckDernoncourt - Either not on any list 0% jury duty....on one or both of those lists >0%. I don't see anything that points to registering as a voter carries more weight than having a license or ID.

Not really an answer to the actual question, but:
For King County, WA

How was I chosen for jury duty?
Your name was selected at random from a list of names generated from
voter registration, driver’s license, and "identicard" records. Every
year the Administrative Office for the Courts in Olympia creates a new
list of names for every court in King County. It is possible that you
will be summoned by one or more courts in the same year or over the
course of several years.

https://kingcounty.gov/en/court/superior-court/courts-jails-legal-system/jury-duty/jury-duty-faq-landing-page
So, voter registration is in there, but does not seem to be a 'more likely' influence.

Some subtle points: Suppose that you got your driver's license while you lived in Tacoma and then moved to Seattle. Until you either update your driver's license address (which most people don't do promptly even if they should, if they don't move to a new state) or register to vote, you still probably won't be in the King County jury pool and the jury summons sent to your Tacoma address will go undelivered. Also, most states have a policy of not repeatedly calling someone for jury duty once they have served and a new county often results in a clean slate for past jury service.

@ohwilleke Well, in Washington state, I've been asked to serve multiple times.  So it's not like they go asking every individual.  But, they have "not repeatedly" called upon me within a short timespan.  Each time I've been asked has been years apart.  And the last two times, my only duty was to call in, and the automated recording never asked me to actually come to the courthouse.  (I may have needed to call multiple days, but eventually the recording stated I was dismissed from further duty for this jury term.)

If I'm reading this correctly, it sounds like it's not possible to select someone for jury duty if they're not registered to vote and don't have a driver's license or an identicard. If that's true, by registering to vote, someone with no license/identicard sees an arbitrarily large increase in their relative likelihood of being selected for jury duty - their chance has gone from 0% to something greater than 0%.

Depends on whether you've been on the list already...
Apparently for Washington state the list is compiled of data from the voter registry, drivers-licenses and non-driver id cards, see here or here.
So if you already possessed a drivers license or a non-driver ID then: No, you were already on that list.
While if you never held a drivers license or a non-driver ID, then: Yes, you are NOW on that list. Though according to the stats on Washington state (drivers licenses and population stats (p.31)), it seems as if already lots of people have a driver license so either you already are on the list or at least the list is probably already quite filled so that your individual chance is quite low.
I'd assume that the list is compiled by merging the 3 lists (once on one list = being on the list) rather than adding (1 chance for every list entry up to 3 times, but also loads more names).
